# "Fn::Join" with delimiter from a parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to parametise the delimiter used by an Fn::Join, e.g. at first I had:

```
"Name" : { "Fn::Join" : [ ".", [ 
           { "Ref":"serviceName"}, { "Ref": "environment" } ] ] },
```

Which works well, but then I changed it to:

```
"Name" : { "Fn::Join" : [ {"Ref":"HostNameSeparator"}, [
           { "Ref":"serviceName"}, { "Ref": "environment" } ] ] },
```

I get the following error from the validation phase:

```
A client error (ValidationError) occurred when calling the
ValidateTemplate operation: Template error: every Fn::Join object
requires two parameters, (1) a string delimiter and (2) a list of
strings to be joined or a function that returns a list of strings
(such as Fn::GetAZs) to be joined.
```

Is it possible to do what I want, i.e. pass the Join delimiter as a template parameter?

(I've shortened the examples above for clarity sake, please ignore typos)

Comment: Not all the CFN statements/functions accept `Ref`. The error you received is quite straight forward.

Comment: Yea I got that and was hoping I'm missing something since Ref does return a string. For now I ended up calculating the value in the shell and passing it as a parameter, but it isn't DRY.

Comment: This should work.  According to Amazon's documentation, "For the Fn::Join delimiter, you can use the Ref function."  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html  Is HostNameSeparator defined?

Comment: After attempting to reproduce this situation, it looks like Amazon's documentation is wrong.  I'd recommend filing a bug with them, and as a workaround, you could use "" as a delimiter, and add the Ref to the delimiter in between each of the items in your list (though I know this is unpleasant if your list is very long).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @JoshEdwards. I'll look for the location to file a bug report.

Comment: Update: AWS documentation at the link given by @Josh Edwards was updated to reflect that the delimiter parameter can take only a simple string, not a function. I was hoping they'll update the code to match the docs...

Comment: Yeah, I would've preferred that they fix the code as well, but at least they're in sync now.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using a CustomResource.
This CloudFormation Template is ready to run and illustrates how it could work. Delimiter is passed as a parameter and you'll find the joined string in the Outputs of the stack.

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Example Join",
    "Parameters": {
        "Delimiter": {
            "Type": "String"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "LambdaExecutionRole": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Properties": {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
                            },
                            "Action": ["sts:AssumeRole"]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Path": "/",
                "Policies": [
                    {
                        "PolicyName": "root",
                        "PolicyDocument": {
                            "Version": "2012-10-17",
                            "Statement": [
                                {
                                    "Effect": "Allow",
                                    "Action": [
                                        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                                        "logs:CreateLogStream",
                                        "logs:PutLogEvents"
                                    ],
                                    "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Effect": "Allow",
                                    "Action": [
                                        "cloudformation:DescribeStacks"
                                    ],
                                    "Resource": "*"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "LambdaJoin": {
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "Properties": {
                "Code": {
                    "ZipFile":  { "Fn::Join": ["\n", [
                        "var response = require('cfn-response');\n",
                        "exports.handler = function (event, context) {\n",
                        "if (event.RequestType === 'Delete') {\n",
                        "return response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, {}, event.PhysicalResourceId);\n",
                        "}\n",
                        "var delimiter = event.ResourceProperties.delimiter || '';\n",
                        "var strings = event.ResourceProperties.strings || [];\n",
                        "return response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, { string: strings.join(delimiter) }, event.PhysicalResourceId);\n",
                        "};\n"
                    ]]}
                },
                "Handler": "index.handler",
                "Runtime": "nodejs",
                "Timeout": "10",
                "Role": { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["LambdaExecutionRole", "Arn"] }
            }
        },
        "CustomJoin": {
            "Type": "Custom::Join",
            "Version": "1.0",
            "Properties": {
                "ServiceToken": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["LambdaJoin", "Arn"] },
                "delimiter": { "Ref": "Delimiter" },
                "strings": ["first", "second", "third"]
            },
            "DependsOn": ["LambdaJoin"]
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "JoinedString": {
            "Value": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["CustomJoin", "string"] }
        }
    }
}
```